# How to properly query products with URL in woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, web, woocommerce, backend

**how can I query products with title or description like an string in the URL;**
so we passed the the search query with GET method to the URL, and we can get it by `get_query_var('s')`; so How to use this in  this args array?

```
$args = [
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    's'         => get_query_var('s'),
    'meta_query' => [],
];
WP_Query($args);
```

is `'s' => get_query_var('s'),` the best soloution for searching here? **My codes work but i'm seeking for a better searching functionality!** Any idea?